# oracle database gets connected without tns entry

Tags: oracle11g

I am new to the oracle database.
I installed OracleXE 11g on my machine. I created a separate test database[SID:testDB] from oracle default database(XE) referring this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCYIo2Pkke4). i created below things:

1. created windows service- OracleServicetestDB using below cmd:
   oradim -new -sid testDB -startmode auto -pfile initTestDB.ora
2. created database
3. executed sql scripts 
   SQL> @?\rdbms\admin\catalog.sql
   SQL> @?\rdbms\admin\catproc.sql
4. created user

After creating user/schema for this new database i am able to make connect it from sql developer and java/jdbc programme from other machine on the network.

I am surprised that i have not created any TNS listener or TNS entry for this database in tnsnames.ora but still i am able to connect with this database locally and remotely.
i am expecting answers of below questions:

1. how my testDB is connected without tns entry?
2. if testDB is depend on XE service/listener, how i configure OracleServicetestDB to seperate from XE services ?
3. List item

java/jdbc code:

```html
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class FirstExample {
 // JDBC driver name and database URL
 static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
 static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:testDB";

 // Database credentials
 static final String USER = "testDBUser";
 static final String PASS = "password";

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Connection conn = null;
  try {
   // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
   Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

   // STEP 3: Open a connection
   System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
   System.out.println("Connected.");

   conn.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tnsnames.ora is used for the openers (apps/tools) depending on driver used and somtimes connection settings; the Java driver can handle most cases *without* tnsnames, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/urls.htm#JJDBC08200 and note that "TNSnames alias" is only one of several options.

Listener is configured in ORAHOME/network/admin/**listener.ora** and usually the defaults don't require any change. On Windows listener runs as a service (a Windows service, not to be confused with an Oracle service-name!) and starts automatically. On both Unix and Windows you have one listener even if you have multiple database instances/SIDs.

Comment: thanks dave for replying, but.. i am connecting via sql developer too which is a tool and i have not made any tns entry for my db instance. generally we get the below error in such cases error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID